Cannot get NextJs to revalidate my Path Within the API Route
I need to revalidate my path after performing logic server-side, however nothing is revalidating.
Here is my server-side API within Nextjs:
import { apiAuth } from '@/helpers/api-auth';
import { auth } from '@/lib/auth';
import { isCSRFValid } from '@/lib/csrf';
import { prisma } from '@repo/database';
import type { Session } from 'next-auth';
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache';

interface Row {
  original: {
    id: string;
  };
}

const deleteWebhook = async (webhookId: string): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const session: Session | null = await auth();

    if (!session) {
      throw new Error('Invalid session');
    }

    await prisma.webhook.update({
      where: { id: webhookId },
      data: { deleted: true },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    const errMsg = 'Error soft-deleting webhook';
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error(errMsg);
  }
};

export const POST = apiAuth(async (req) => {
  const { rows }: { rows: Row[] } = await req.json();

  for (const row of rows) {
    await deleteWebhook(row.original.id);
  }

  // revalidatePath('/5555555555/webhooks');
  revalidatePath('/[orgId]/webhooks', 'page');
  // revalidateTag('webhooks');

  return new Response(`deleted ${rows.length} webhooks`, { status: 200, statusText: 'OK' });
});

And here is the handler where I am calling the API:
  const handleDelete = useCallback(async () => {
    const rows = table.getSelectedRowModel().rows;
    try {
      await api.request('/api/delete-webhook', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: { rows },
      });
    } catch (error: unknown) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        logger.captureException(error);
      }
    }

    // setWebhookData((prevData) => filterWebhookData(prevData, rows));
    table.setRowSelection({});
  }, [api, table, setWebhookData]);

The function is being called with no errors, however revalidatePath doesn't seem to be performing any action. Can anyone help me out?
